# Storing a String and ouputting to Multiple Cells in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string

I currently have  code set up that will loop through all the worksheets in my workbook, paste a date in a cell which, when non blank, will have the remaining cells in the row populate with data.

At the beginning of each row - I have a formula that will say "Error" if any of the cells in that row has an error in it. like this:
[image]

I then have another loop which will go back through each worksheet and check to see if there is an error in that cell and if so, will go to the first sheet in the workbook to a specific cell and add "Error on xyz Tab". If there are multiple errors, it'll go to the next row down and paste it. So it looks like this:

[image]

I'm thinking instead of looping through each sheet again, could i store the text string in a variable/array and just paste it on the front sheet at the end of the loop in the same manner?

This is the code for the error loop that's currently set up:

```
For I = 1 To WS_Count 
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Activate

    Cells.Find(What:="Date", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).End(xlDown).Offset(0, -1).Activate

    If ActiveCell.Value = "Error" Then        
        Application.Goto "ErrorCheck" 

        If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = vbNullString Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Error on " & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name & " " & Hour(Now) & "00"
        Else
            Selection.End(xlDown).Activate                
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Error on " & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name & " " & Hour(Now) & "00"
        End If

    Else

    End If
Next I
```

Comment: Is it currently performing badly or something?

Comment: not really - just seems redundant/good learning experience

Comment: I like your current approach but if you want to use an array or something, look at redim preserve and then google pasting arrays to ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with this I personally wouldn't want to use an array. I would prefer using a collection. It is easier because you do not know the parameters for your array so it is tough to give it dimensions.

Nonetheless find below a possible solution. Work it to your needs. I have yet to test or debug myself. But should do the trick.

```
Sub ErrorCheck()

    Dim x As Long, lRow1 As Long, lRow2 As Long
    Dim myCollection As New Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet

    Set mySheet = Sheets("ErrorCheckSheet")

    'create the for loop to cycle through worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'set the lrow to iterate through column
        'set the colum for your need - "Error" column
        lRow1 = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'IF lRow does not match your cell, use a static variable ie. 50
        'assuming your data starts in row 2 as per picture
        For x = 2 To lRow1
            'check each cell for error text
            If ws.Range("A" & x).Text = "Error" Then
                'when found add to collection
                'adjust to meet your cell you want to input into collection
                myCollection.Add ws.Range("B" & x).Text
            End If
        Next x
     Next ws
     'once you have completely cycled through your workbook your collection will now be loaded
    For x = 1 To myCollection.Count
        'set the lrow on the sheet you want to enter the data in
        lRow2 = mySheet.Range("U" & mySheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'now set the variable
        mySheet.Range("U" & lRow2).Value = "Error on" & myCollection(x)
    Next x

    Set myCollection = New Collection
    Set mySheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: will the end(x1Up).row work for this case b/c it's all forumlas?

Comment: end(xlup) will still work with formulae. I have just double checked this.

Comment: @novawaly If this code works and solves your problem please mark as answer.